# How do I stop a Windows 10 machine sleeping while onedrive is syncing

Tags: windows-10, sleep, onedrive

I have a laptop that I wish to remain active untill onedrive has backup all local files, however it seems onedrive does not prevent the laptop from sleeping even if it still have thousands of files to upload.

(I don't mind the laptop forcing a sleep if battery is getting low.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A request for this very feature was done on Microsoft's UserVoice
[Prevent sleep until sync is done option](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913522-onedrive-on-windows/suggestions/7127804-prevent-sleep-until-sync-is-done-option).
This was in 2015, and while users are still asking and upvoting for it,
there was no answer forthcoming from Microsoft.

I think that if your computer is about to sync thousands of files,
your best bet is to disable sleep temporarily until it finishes.

Rather than temporarily changing the power scheme settings,
a handy application to use is
[Insomnia](https://dlaa.me/blog/post/10104830).
Just launching it will block sleep, until it is closed.

[image]

Comment: Note that there is a slight upgrade of Insomnia, but it works just as before (it's now dockable as well). And the "native" 64-bit version is not even 100 KBytes — definitely *not* a memory hog! Last but not least: Insomnia does *not* override the screen saver, which will continue to be active, thus doing its job of protecting the screen :)